# Trouble Installing Flutter on OSX

Tags: dart, flutter

I followed the install instructions for Flutter on OSX, and ended up with this error:

```
"Dart_NewStringFromUTF8 expects argument 'str' to be valid UTF-8."
```

Checking the github issues, [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8612) one seems to be closed but was not helpful in resolving. I have no weird characters in my file path.

I cannot find anything else on it that will resolve this error, nor do I know what/where to check to find out what is causing this. Anyone else ran into this issue on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this error by running flutter in verbose mode:

```
flutter doctor -v
```

This gave me clues on where the issue was on my machine. There was a directory with a non UTF-8 character and that tripped up the installation process. Renaming that directory solved the error.